# Median of an array in Ruby not floating

Tags: ruby, arrays, median

OK folks...I could use some help on getting the median of an array in ruby

Here is my code:

```
def median(array)
  array.sort! # sort the array
  elements = array.count # count the elements in the array
  center =  elements/2 # find the center of the array
  elements.even? ? (array[center] + array[center+1])/2 : array[center]  # if elements are even take both the center numbers of array and divide in half, if odd...get the center number
end
```

Just not certain where to apply the .to_f since it wont return anything needing a float.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried? `(array[center].to_f + array[center+1].to_f)/2 : array[center]`

Comment: No needs to use `to_f`, just divide by `2.0`

Comment: Figured it out with a bunch of help from all...thanks.https://gist.github.com/jrosaaen/8573539

Comment: Shouldn't you use "center = (elements - 1) / 2" instead ? As your array is 0-indexed, if elements equals 2 (e.g. with this array [5, 10]), your center equals 1 ("center = elements / 2"). "elements" being even, your median would be "(array[center] + array[center+1]) / 2", that is "10 + nil" because "center + 1" would be out-of-bounds.

This fix should be used along with Yevgeniy Anfilofyev's one.

Answer (score 0):

I realized you've solved your own problem already, but this version is a little cleaner and safer:

```
def median(array)
  raise ArgumentError, 'Cannot find the median on an empty array' if array.size == 0
  sorted = array.sort
  midpoint, remainder = sorted.length.divmod(2)
  if remainder == 0 # even count, average middle two
    sorted[midpoint-1,2].inject(:+) / 2.0
  else
    sorted[midpoint]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerable-statistics.

https://github.com/mrkn/enumerable-statistics

This gem was created by the Ruby committer as a C extension.
I think it is reliable and fast.

It Returns int if the number of array elements is odd. If the number of array elements is even, it returns a float.

```rb
require "enumerable/statistics"

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.median # => 3
arr.median.class # => Integer

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr.median # => 3.5
```

Other useful methods are also available.

`mean`, `variance`, `stdev`, `mean_variance`, `mean_stdev`, `percentile`, `value_counts` `histogram`